# What is the password for a Local HubL Server?

Tags: hubspot

I am following the documentation here http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/tools/local-hubl-server but when running the local-hubl-server Batch file (after unzipping the package), the browser opens a username/password window. What are the credentials? I tried root/root, admin/admin and blank username and password. I also checked the config.yaml file but I couldn't see any parameter to set the username and password. I am running on Windows 7 and JDK 1.8.0_144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was another service was running in the same port as the HubL server was supposed to run. Edited the port in the config.yaml file and no username/password prompt appeared anymore.